# MySQL Combine data from two tables with table name

Tags: mysql

I currently have two tables, table1 and table2. These tables have the same structure, but contain different data.

What I need is a query that will combine the data of table1 and table2 together, and also specify which table the data came from.

For example, if table1 and table2 looked like:

```
+------+     +------+
| name |     | name |
+------+     +------+
| Bob  |     | Rob  |
+------+ and +------+
```

I would like a resulting table of:

```
+------+--------+
| name |  from  |
+------+--------+
| Bob  | table1 |
+------+--------+
| Rob  | table2 |
+------+--------+
```

The only SQL that I came up with was:

```
SELECT name FROM table1 UNION SELECT name FROM table2;
```

But that does not add the table name the row came from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**query**

```
SELECT name, 'table1' as `from`
FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT name, 'table2' as `from`
FROM table2
;
```

**output**

```
+------+--------+
| name |  from  |
+------+--------+
| Bob  | table1 |
| Rob  | table2 |
+------+--------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c9b3/9)

Answer (score -1):

It is best not to use 'from' as a resulting column, since it is a reserved word in SQL, but you can do

```
SELECT name, 'table1' AS [from] FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT name, 'table2' AS [from] FROM table2
```

Comment: syntax [from] should be `\`from\``